Relationships between busy beaver functions
Is there a survey on the behavior and relationships between different busy-beaver-like functions when we ignore $O(1)$ changes in $n$?  If not, here are my notes and some specific questions.
Exact growth rates of busy-beaver-like functions depend on the choice of the Turing-complete representation/model.  However, for compact encodings of code (or if we use code + data instead of just code), we get representation-independence if we ignore $O(\log n)$ changes in input length ($n$ is always the number of bits), i.e. for (monotonic) busy-beaver-like functions $B_i$ and $B_j$, we have $∃c \, ∀n>1 \, B_j(n) < B_i(n+⌈c \log n⌉) < B_j(n+⌈2c \log n⌉)$.
However, if we ignore only $O(1)$ length changes, then instead of all busy-beaver-like functions being alike, we get natural equivalence classes, such as $B_1$ through $B_4$ below, with subtle relationships between them.
Fix a prefix universal Turing machine $U$.  (That is for every Turing machine $M$, there is input prefix $s_M$ such that on $s_M t$ halting and output before reaching the end of $s_M t$ is equivalent to that for $M$ on $t$.)  The choice of $U$ and whether we use the same $U$ for $B_1$ through $B_4$ does not affect the discussion and conjectures, as it corresponds to only $O(1)$ change in input length.
Define the following busy beaver functions: $\DeclareMathOperator{\lg}{lg}$ 
$B_1$ (prefix free): Like $B_4$ but must halt before reaching input end.
$B_2$ (Chaitin's constant based):  $B_2(n) = \min(t:P_∞ - P_t < 2^{-n})$ where $P_t$ is halting probability for $t$ steps using $U$ on random data.
$B_3$ (autohalt on input end; binary tape): Like $B_4$ but auto-halt if input end (end marker) is reached.
$B_4$ (the regular one): $B_4(n)$ is the longest time $U$ takes to halt on a binary string of length $≤n$ followed by the end marker.
We have $B_1(n+O(1)) ≤ B_2(n+O(1)) ≤ B_3(n+O(1)) ≤ B_4(n+O(1)) ≤ B_1(n+K(n)+O(1))$ where $K$ is prefix-free Kolmogorov complexity (in bits).  $K(n) ≤ \lg n + \lg \lg n + ... + O(1)$; the difference is i.o. (infinitely often) only $O(\log^* n)$.
$B_3(n)$ is i.o. $B_2(n + \lg n + ω(1))$; for example this happens when the Chaitin's constant has a long enough string of zeroes.  I expect that $B_2(n)$ is i.o. $B_1(n  + \lg n + ω(1))$ and $B_4(n)$ is i.o. $B_3(n  + \lg n + ω(1))$.  $B_1(n+O(1))$, $B_2(n+O(1))$ and $B_4(n+O(1))$ are unaffected by alphabet size (where $n$ measures length in bits rather than characters); not sure about $B_3$.
I expect that $B_2(n)$ is $B_1(n+ω(1))$, and that for $1-o(1)$ density of $n$, $B_2(n)$ is $B_1(n + \lg n + ω(1))$ (how do you prove this?).
Conjectures:

For every $ε>0$, for lim sup $\; >1-ε$ density of $n$, $B_4(n)$ is $B_2(n+O(1))$ (i.e. below $B_2(n+c_ε)$ for some constant $c_ε$).
$(B_4(n), B_4(n+O(1)))$ interval i.o. includes $\lg n + ω(1)$ values of $B_2$.
$(B_2(n), B_2(n+1))$ interval i.o. includes $Ω(\log \log n)$ values of $B_4$.
For every $c$, there is a total computable $f$ such that i.o. $B_4(n+c)$ < $f(B_4(n))$.
For every choice of $U$ and $ε>0$, $B_2(B_2^{-1}(x)+ε)$ dominates every total computable function.  (Note that $B_2$ makes sense for non-integral arguments (but these are not used for (2)).)

We can also conjecture (2)-(4) using $B_1$ or $B_3$ in place of $B_4$.
Question: Are these conjectures true?  As they are likely hard, I would be happy with an answer for just one of them.  I am also fine with an expository answer on this topic.
Notes:

For (1), the intuition is that a random length does not help much for $B_4$ over $B_2$.
For (2), the intuition is that a length can suddenly become maximally useful for $B_4$.
For (3), we only use $Ω(\log \log n)$ since every $(B_2(n), B_2(n+m))$ interval includes at most $m + K(m) + (1+o(1)) \lg K(n)$ values of $B_4$ (and same for $B_1$ in place of $B_4$).  The reason is that a busy beaver code gives $n±K(n)±O(1)$ bits of Chaitin's constant, and with $(1+o(1)) \lg K(n)$ bits (which is at most $(1+o(1)) \lg \lg n$) we can supply a baseline precision, and then we can supply a more precise approximation of Chaitin's constant.
For (4), the intuition is that powerful new busy beavers occur somewhat randomly.  Note that such an $f$ noncomputably depends on $c$.
For (5), the intuition is that $B_2$ uses a large ensemble of busy-beaver-like functions, giving us a smooth behavior.

Overall, $B_2$ appears to be the best choice if we want a single yardstick for busy-beaver-like growth rates. $B_3$ (i.e. how long might it take to reach input end) seems the least natural, but still useful for illustration.
